# lumen-passport cannot php artisan migrate?

Tags: php, lumen

i got a problem when trying to install dusterio/lumen-passport. i've tried based on the step by step that they give at [github](https://github.com/dusterio/lumen-passport) and [packagist.org](https://packagist.org/packages/dusterio/lumen-passport) .

the problem is every time i do the

> php artisan migrate

command, it's always saying someting like:

> In PassportServiceProvider.php line 299:
>
> > Call to undefined function Laravel\Passport\config_path()

and here is my bootsrap/app.php

```
<?php

require_once __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

try {
    (new Dotenv\Dotenv(__DIR__.'/../'))->load();
} catch (Dotenv\Exception\InvalidPathException $e) {
    //
}

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Create The Application
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here we will load the environment and create the application instance
| that serves as the central piece of this framework. We'll use this
| application as an "IoC" container and router for this framework.
|
*/

$app = new Laravel\Lumen\Application(
    realpath(__DIR__.'/../')
);

 $app->withFacades();

 $app->withEloquent();

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Register Container Bindings
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Now we will register a few bindings in the service container. We will
| register the exception handler and the console kernel. You may add
| your own bindings here if you like or you can make another file.
|
*/

$app->singleton(
    Illuminate\Contracts\Debug\ExceptionHandler::class,
    App\Exceptions\Handler::class
);

$app->singleton(
    Illuminate\Contracts\Console\Kernel::class,
    App\Console\Kernel::class
);

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Register Middleware
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Next, we will register the middleware with the application. These can
| be global middleware that run before and after each request into a
| route or middleware that'll be assigned to some specific routes.
|
*/

// $app->middleware([
//    App\Http\Middleware\ExampleMiddleware::class
// ]);

 $app->routeMiddleware([
     'auth' => App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
 ]);

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Register Service Providers
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here we will register all of the application's service providers which
| are used to bind services into the container. Service providers are
| totally optional, so you are not required to uncomment this line.
|
*/

$app->register(App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::class);
$app->register(App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider::class);
$app->register(App\Providers\EventServiceProvider::class);
$app->register(Laravel\Passport\PassportServiceProvider::class);
$app->register(Dusterio\LumenPassport\PassportServiceProvider::class);

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Load The Application Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Next we will include the routes file so that they can all be added to
| the application. This will provide all of the URLs the application
| can respond to, as well as the controllers that may handle them.
|
*/

$app->router->group([
    'namespace' => 'App\Http\Controllers',
], function ($router) {
    require __DIR__.'/../routes/web.php';
});

return $app;
```

am i did something wrong ? i've tried to search it on google but i don't find anything yet :(

Comment: after trying to find for many hour about the problem, i find out that laravel passport has been updated to v6.0 on packagist.org/packages/laravel/passport yesterday (9 April 2018). and when i downgrade the version of laravel/passport to v5.0.3 (adding "laravel/passport": "5.0.3" on required composer json) it works! but i still not find out how if i want to use laravel/passport v6. anyone could you help me ?

Answer (score 1):

You can add helpers folder in app folder and add helpers.php file `app/helpers/helpers.php`

inside `helpers.php` add

```
<?php
if ( ! function_exists('config_path'))
{
    /**
     * Get the configuration path.
     *
     * @param  string $path
     * @return string
     */
    function config_path($path = '')
    {
        return app()->basePath() . '/config' . ($path ? '/' . $path : $path);
    }
}
```

then add this to composer.json

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    },
    "files": [
        "app/helpers/helpers.php"
    ]
},
```

then run,

```
composer dump-autoload
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because Lumen doesn't have some of the laravel helper functions. In this case it's 'config_path()' function.

Here is the Solution

1. Install the latest Passport Package
2. Install this plugin `composer require irazasyed/larasupport`
3. Add below class to your service provider (app.php)

   `$app->register(Irazasyed\Larasupport\Providers\ArtisanServiceProvider::class);`
4. Update composer using `composer update`
5. Do your migrate now (php artisan migrate)

This should be solved your issue.